# your content folder is not writable wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can somebody help me please. I have getting a headache. I recently moved my server. The website run as normal but when I try to add content. My wordpress site shown. "your content folder is not writable"

I have did changing the permission to 777 to recursive folders but it won't work. I also tried to change it from ssh which code

```
chmod -R 777 /home/admin/public_html/wp-content/uploads
```

surprisingly, the admin dashboard still show the same error. I really appreciate any helps. Thank you.

Comment: First of all. Try to check the permissions of your total `WP_installation`. So what permissions does wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes have?. And the permissions inside wp-content? your themes and plug-ins?

Comment: I did, I checked all the permission but it still doesn't work. It is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

That's a server permission problem. According to the WP docs:

> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

*And, FYI, search first for a common issue like permissions; there are many answers already on WP permissions.*